# sql join with extra conditions

Tags: sql-server, database

t1:

```
items, id, [...]
a      12       
b      21
c      34
d      45
e      52
```

t2:

```
items order 
a      1
b      2
others 3
```

Desired results:

```
items, id, [...], order
a      12         1
b      21         2
c      34         3
d      45         3
e      52         3
```

I basically want everything that doesnt match 'a', 'b', to get the ordering of 'others'. But with inner join Im not sure how to do it, I can only join if there is a match, do I have to use subquery for something simply like this?

```
Select t1.items, t1.id, t2.order
t1
inner join 
t2
On t1.items = t.items
```

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a big box popped up on the screen suggesting that you add a tag for the **specific DBMS** you're using. You still have not done so. *database* is not a **specific DBMS**. What DBMS are you using? They vary in features and syntax, so it is extremely relevant for you to include a tag for it. (And next time, don't ignore the box that tells you so.) You might also include an attempt that will actually execute; the one you posted isn't valid syntax in any SQL dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `join` like this:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.order, t2other.order) as ordering
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.items = t2.items left join
     t2 t2other
     on t2other.items = 'other';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no t1.item = order you'll get NULL.

```
select items, id, IsNull(t2.order, 3) order
from t1
     left join t2 on t1.items = t2.items;
```

Or using a CASE statement:

```
select items, id,
       case when t1.items = 'a' or t1.items = 'b' the t2.order
            else 3
       end as order
from t1
     left join t2 on t1.items = t2.items;
```